# Cannot run ASP.NET Core Web API on Azure Devops deployment group (self-hosted)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-webapi, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Im working on a simple deployment pipeline with azure devops. I created a deployment pipeline running on a **self hosted** ubuntu deployment group.
The pipeline looks like this:

- Download artifacts from CI pipeline (created with dotnet publish)
- Stop running deployment
- Unzip the ASP.NET Core Web API to the deployment directory
- Run new deployment with `dotnet MyApp.dll`

The first two steps work as expected. However, when the `dotnet My App.dll` command is run, the process runs for 10 seconds with following "error" message being printed at the end:

```
The STDIO streams did not close within 10 seconds of the exit event from process '/usr/bin/bash'. This may indicate a child process inherited the STDIO streams and has not yet exited.
```

The deployment task is successful despite the message and the app not running. I tried to work around this feature by using `nohup &` and relocating the command output. After some research I found that all processes started by a pipeline agent are stopped after the agent's work is done - meaning this behaviour is intended and my understanding of azure deployments/agents is wrong.
How do I **deploy and run** my app in an automated way on my own ubuntu machine using azure devops pipelines?

Comment: Have you tried run the `dotnet MyApp.dll` directly on the self hosted agent? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053614/publishing-test-results-in-azuredevops-hangs

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, running the app directly works fine. Running it through the pipeline works too but the process is killed after 10 seconds - the agent performs a cleanup and stops every process it started during the pipeline after all jobs are completed. I managed to work around it by setting the `Process.clean` variable to `false` but its kinda dirty and certainly not what the developers intended.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I think you are already in the correct way. Setting `Process.clean` variable to `false` is the solution to stop agent to clean up the processes. You could check the similar thread https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/release-pipeline-killed-my-node-server-process-in/497786

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Well... it solves the problem but it doesn't seem to be a "clean" way of doing it. Regardless, thank you for your answer. I guess this solution is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I deploy and run my app in an automated way on my own ubuntu machine using azure devops pipelines?

You are already on the right way.

All the process launched in the pipeline will be finished/clean up  in “Finalize Job” step when the pipeline is over.

If you don't want the process to be closed, please try set variable `Process.clean= false` to stops the "finalize job" step from killing all processes.

But when you create a new pipeline next time, you need to close the app before starting it.